# SWT: How to color the shell border?

Tags: swt

Could you please tell me how I could add color to the borders of the shell(Around the client area)? Is it possible to change the color of the native border?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. The color is decided and painted by the windowing system, not the application itself.